# Holograms - interference image, can I tell if the 2nd diode is good for holograms by comparing fringes?

Tags: coherence, length

I've created two fringe images - one of a laser diode that's able to make holograms which outputs 5mW.

The second laser outputs 20mW and so far I've not been able to make a hologram with it.

I had a look at how to make fringe patterns to check the coherence of the lasers, and this is what I finally came up with:

[Two fringe images](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipMjIrmVOZbQof4pkhoTXyb_CfpQLFnUcksSuuaCYLIKQKBTdMvlWr61kpOG5wjw4g?key=YVdnX0ViSHhyTU9mcExDV1pCZ1g1QkRlTFFBSzRR)

Is it possible by comparing the two images to say that the 20mW laser should be able to make holograms, and I've just messed the picture up somehow?

I think if the coherence distance of the beam is low and bad for holograms, the fringes would be close together relative to a better hologram laser?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The fringes should be the same width if the the laser color is roughly the same. A wider-band laser would simply produce lower contrast fringes. I see pretty good contrast in both images, so either laser should produce a decent hologram. Could it be that you are over-exposing the film with the 20mW laser?

Comment: It's the litiholo auto-developing film, which stops the film from becoming over-exposed some how. I think my laser stand may be too unstable or the diode was still warming up... I'll try again with a firmer stand.